# Implicit differentiation gives different answer

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to implicitly differentiate the following equation: $\frac{x+f(x)}{c+f(x)}=4$ where $c$ is a constant.

Here's what I get:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{dx}\left(\frac{x+f(x)}{c+f(x)}\right)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(4)
$$
$$
\frac{(1+f'(x))(c+f(x))-(x+f(x))(f'(x))}{(c+f(x))^2}=0
$$
$$
\frac{c+f(x)+cf'(x)+f(x)f'(x)-xf'(x)-f(x)f'(x)}{(c+f(x))^2}=0
$$
$$
c+f(x)+cf'(x)-xf'(x)=0
$$
$$
c+f(x)=xf'(x)-cf'(x)
$$
$$
f'(x)=\frac{c+f(x)}{x-c}
$$

However, when I isolate $f(x)$ first...
$$
\frac{x+f(x)}{c+f(x)}=4
$$
$$
x+f(x)=4c+4f(x)
$$
$$
x-4c=3f(x)
$$
$$
\frac{x}{3}-\frac{4}{3}c=f(x)
$$

... I get a different answer:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x}{3}-\frac{4}{3}c\right)
$$
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Hopefully someone can shed some light on where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not standard to use `\prime` for derivatives because it renders a bit strange. I swapped it for a bunch of `'`.

Comment: Nothing’s wrong. Substitute your known expression for $f(x)$ and it all checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\frac{x+f(x)}{c+f(x)}=4
$ find $f(x)$
$$4c+4f(x)=x+f(x)\\3f(x)=x-4c\\f(x)= \frac 13 (x-4c) $$ now you can easily see $f'(x)=\frac 13$  or   put $f(x)$ into $f'(x)=\frac{c+f(x)}{x-c}$
$$f'(x)=\frac{c+\frac 13 (x-4c)}{x-c}=\frac 13
$$